# How can I cool an under the counter icemaker?

Tags: exhaust-fan, cooling

We have a Subzero under the counter ice maker.  During our hot summer days it really gets hot and slows the ice production down to a crawl. We thought we would install a cooling fan on the wall behind it or push an exhaust fan through the wall to the outside. But we are not sure which one would be the most effective.  Right now we have drilled holes in the adjacent cabinet and I leave that door open and vent the heat into the room.  Winter it's okay solution but summer no way. Which would be best and what type of fan system do I need?

Comment: I can't imagine a Subzero ever under-performing. Assuming the unit has been installed correctly, are you sure it's not malfunctioning in some way? or is not in need of maintenance?

Comment: I agree. This makes me suspect the unit wasn't installed with the right clearances.

Answer (score 1):

I would 'push' and 'pull' with "[muffin fans](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102825)"

I would locate the 'push' side in the toe-kick area in the cabinet to the left and put the 'pull fan inside the top left wall (in the cabinet to the right of the icemaker)  this should pull out the hot air at the top and supplement with relatively cooler air near the floor.  Fan shrouding, plug in timer for night time operation (muffin fans are loud) and safe electrical wiring are left to the reader to implement properly.

[image]

Comment: I used too similar fans to cool a hallway closet I am using for a home theater utility room.  I calculated that it replaced the air once every few minutes.  It is amazing what a little air movement can do.  Lowered it from 120 to 80 degrees.